# How to skip values from SQL if not sharing ID with other table

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sql, asp.net

I am trying to create a list of cities to be shown on a dropdown list, but I want to skip the ones who doesn't share a value with other list. There's an example:

[image: Example of the tables I have]

As you can see, any of my advertisers is in Chicago, so I want to skip this city from my dropdown list. This is how is it being shown:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cities= new CitiesController().FetchAll();
        listCity = cities.ToList();
    }
```

.

```
 <% for (int i = 0; i < listCity.Count; i++) { %>
     <% var sec = listaCity[i];%>
 <option value="c.<%= sec.CityId %>"><%= sec.Name %></option>
      <% } %>
```

This shows ALL the cities and I don't know how to skip the ones whose cityID doesn't appear at advertiser's cityID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX) to find the common items between two list. You can alternatively use Linq [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx) to acheive what you want.

```
 var advertiserList = // advertiser's city list
 var cities = new CategoryController().FetchAll();
 var listCity  = cities.Where (a => advertiserList.Select(b => b.cityID).Contains(a.cityID)).ToList();
```

`listCity` will give you the list of cities only if it's present in `advertiserList`

Comment: Thank you very much, the last line helped me figure out how to make it. It showed me exactly the cities I wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you have a var with all advertisers **advertisers** and a var with all cities **cities** you could do this:

```
var citiesToDisplay = from city in cities join adv in advertisers on city.cityID equals adv.cityID 
select city;
```